# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token WSAStartup (versionWanted, &wsaData);

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifdef __linux__
#include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    #define WSACleanup()
    #define closeConnection(fd) ::close(fd)
#elif _WIN32
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    WORD versionWanted = MAKEWORD(1, 1);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup (versionWanted, &wsaData);

    #define closeConnection(fd) closesocket(fd);
#endif
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
using namespace std;
...
```

compiling with this command:

**`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -I include -o main.exe -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32 -static`**

Compile error: 
`error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token WSAStartup (versionWanted, &wsaData);`

Host: Kubuntu 18.04 LTS

Q_1: Why its giving me this error? 
Q_2: Should I use comment... for linking when using mingw64 (or just when on msvc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than initialisations and declarations, all code must be inside a function or method. You need to put the following code inside of a function:

```
WORD versionWanted = MAKEWORD(1, 1);
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup (versionWanted, &wsaData);
```